# Include external library in Qt project indipendently of path

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing a C++ app with Qt that depends on the GNU Scientific Library (GSL).

So far, I have linked GSL in the `.pro` file using `LIBS += /path/to/my/GSL/location -l<name_of_the_library>` and it works, but it depends on where I installed GSL.
I'd like the `.pro` file not to depend on the user-specific GSL path, and possibly include the precompiled libraries (for different OSes) in the project folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In this case it works on all platforms. You have to separate the directory from the library name

```
LIBS += -L/path/to -lpsapi
```

In this case You store your lib files in the project directory.

```
LIBS += -L"$$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/3rdparty/libs/" -lpsapi
```

look at this for more: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html